# OCaml Compilation Error compiling Lablgl and Lablgtk

Tags: opengl, user-interface, compilation, ocaml

I am trying to compile three files - toolbar.ml which uses lablgtk2, window.ml which uses lablgl and main.ml which calls both these files. Here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Compiling files"
eval $(opam config env)
echo "Compiling toolbar"
ocamlc -I +lablgtk2 lablgtk.cma gtkInit.cmo toolbar.ml
echo "Compiling window"
ocamlfind ocamlc window.ml -package lablgl.glut -linkpkg
ocamlc -c main.ml
ocamlc -o run window.cmo main.cmo toolbar.cmo
echo "Running executable"
./run
echo "Clearing up"
rm run main.cmo main.cmi main.o window.cmo window.cmi window.o a.out
rm toolbar.cmo toolbar.cmi
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Error while linking window.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `Glut'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't linking all the packages / creating a new package - this is how I fixed it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Compiling files"
eval $(opam config env)
echo "Compiling toolbar"
ocamlc -a -o toolbar.cma -linkall -I +lablgtk2 lablgtk.cma gtkInit.cmo toolb    ar.ml
echo "Compiling window"
ocamlfind ocamlc -a -o window.cma -linkall window.ml -package lablgl.glut -l    inkpkg
ocamlc -c main.ml
ocamlc -o run window.cma toolbar.cma main.cmo
echo "Running executable"
./run
echo "Clearing up"
rm run main.cmo main.cmi main.o window.cmo window.cmi window.o a.out
rm toolbar.cmo toolbar.cmi
rm window.cma toolbar.cma
```